# Var-Arg method infers Generic Type to be both Object & primitive[] simultaneously

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Unanticipated behavior for Generics and Var-Arg

```
   public static <T> void method(T singleVal, T ... vals) {
      System.out.println(singleVal);
      for(T val : vals) {
        System.out.println(val);
      }
   }
```

called via:

```
   method(0, new int[]{1,2,3});
   //method('a', new char[] {'b','c','d'});  //same behavior
```

Prints:

```
   0
   [I@7699a589   //<--- an array at element 0
```

It happens only when passing it a primitive[].

With int[] in, `T` becomes *both* `Integer` and `int []` ***simultaneously?***

[image: debugEditorVals]

When passing it an Integer[] instead of int [], it behaves as anticipated:

```
method(0, new Integer[]{1,2,3});
//method('a', new Character[] {'b','c','d'});  //same behavior

0
1
2
3
```

Comment: No.  `O` is an `int[][]`.

Comment: This probably shouldn't compile since you've asked the compiler to infer the type of `O` (bad choice of name, BTW, for readability reasons) from two different classes.  This may be covered in the JLS but I couldn't find anything with a cursory search.

Comment: You're probably expecting `int[]` to convert automatically to `Integer[]`.  It doesn't.

Comment: @Jim I edited it to be `T` instead of `O`. It does compile and works with Integer[]. @Luis you are correct it is not converting the int[], but the odd part is `T` is 2 different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer comes from [JLS §15.12.4.2. Evaluate Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2). We've already done overload resolution trivially (there's only one overload in this example), so we know the target method. It's just a matter of evaluating the arguments and making the call.

> The process of evaluating the argument list differs, depending on whether the method being invoked is a fixed arity method or a variable arity method (§8.4.1).
>
> If the method being invoked is a variable arity method `m`, it necessarily has `n > 0` formal parameters. The final formal parameter of `m` necessarily has type `T[]` for some `T`, and `m` is necessarily being invoked with `k ≥ 0` actual argument expressions.
>
> If `m` is being invoked with `k ≠ n` actual argument expressions, or, if `m` is being invoked with `k = n` actual argument expressions and the type of the `k`'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with `T[]`, then the argument list `(e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek)` is evaluated as if it were written as `(e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek })`, where `|T[]|` denotes the erasure (§4.6) of `T[]`.

Now let's see how this word soup applies to your example. The method in question is

```
public static <T> void method(T singleVal, T ... vals)
```

And the argument list is

```
method(0, new int[]{1,2,3});
```

The method `m` has two formal arguments, of types `T` and `T[]`. Since the final argument is of array type and is marked with the variable-arity designator `...`, this is a variable arity method. We're calling it with two arguments, so `k = n` in the above quote. Now, the first argument is of type `int`, which is not valid as a generic argument, so autoboxing takes that to `Integer`. That means `T` is `Integer`. The second argument is `int[]`. Since `k = n`, we're going to wrap this in an array if (and only if) our second argument is *not* assignment compatible with `Integer[]`. And the second argument is `int[]`, not `Integer[]`. Autoboxing won't convert a whole array, so we assume we need to wrap this.

Now, you reasonably ask why this function call can happen at all. After all, we already decided `T` was `Integer`, and now we're saying `T` is `int[]`? Well, I lied. Or, rather, I oversimplified. We didn't *decide* `T` was `Integer`. We decided `T` was *compatible with* `Integer`. Basically, we decided that `T` was *some supertype of* `Integer`. In the absence of any additional information, Java would conclude that `T` should be `Integer`, but it is also happy to widen that during type inference if needed.

In your case, we've already decided that `int[]` is not compatible with `Integer[]` (or with `U[]` for any supertype `U` of `Integer`, to be precise), since `int` is a primitive and we can't autobox on the inside of an array. So we've already made the decision that this is a variable argument call that will be wrapped in an array. That is, the call is getting converted to

```
method(new Integer(0), new int[][]{new int[]{1, 2, 3}});
```

It's just a matter of finding a `T` that works with the method signature

```
// Note: No T... now, we've already made that decision, so it's T[] now.
public static <T> void method(T singleVal, T[] vals)
```

That is, we need a type `T` that is a common supertype of both `Integer` and `int[]`. `Integer` has several supertypes: `Number`, `Comparable<Integer>`, `Serializable`, etc. But only one type is a supertype of *both* `Integer` and an array type: `Object`. That is, you've made a call with `T = Object`.

The lesson here, I think, is that generics and varargs don't play nice, an when autoboxing gets in the mix, they *definitely* don't play nice. Personally, I only use variable arguments with concrete types (so `int...` or `String...` are fair game, but I'd never write `T...`), just to avoid messy business like this.

Comment: thank you for all this. Its very interesting and I just never knew it was possible. Good to know